# Lookup values in SQL through Excel 2013

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to call part information from SQL to Excel. When a user enters a part number, Excel queries the SQL database and retrieves details about the part (price, description, etc).

I was able to import the data, and use a vlookup to pull in the values, however the import is quite large.

There were some VB scripts out in the webs that would pull data directly from the SQL database into the cells, but those are out of date for Excel 2013.

I'm using the following statement for SQL to pull all the data on the table:

```
SELECT 
   PartNum,
   PartDescription,
   UnitPrice
   FROM erp.Part
```

Ideally would like a script that only asks for a specific part, using WHERE PartNum = *part* and returns the requested data in a row.

Thanks in advance for any info/help.

Comment: 1) A little late now, but it would help to know which SQL database you are trying to pull data from. 2) Also, what you probably want are parameters; both [DAO/ACE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff845640.aspx) and [ADO](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms681010(v=vs.85).aspx) support them.

Answer (score 0):

your question is vague at best, and you didnt even provide code youve tried. Here is a basic sql from excel vba script

```
Sub TrackerInput()
    Dim db As DAO.Database
    Dim rs As DAO.Recordset

    Set db = DBEngine.OpenDatabase("pathtoyourfilewhichmightneedotincludecredentialsGoogelitforyourself")

    Dim vAr$
    vAr = "your input of choice" '.ie part number you were suggesting

    Set rs = db.OpenRecordSet("SELECT PartNum, PartDescription, UnitPrice FROM erp.Part WHERE PartNum=" & vAr & ";")
    TheLocationWhereYouWantTheDataReturned.CopyFromRecordset rs

End Sub
```

Your references will need to be set OBV

Answer (score 0):

Solved by handing in my resignation, apparently im too stupid or don't know how to git good enough to do this job anymore. Going to follow my passion and sell umbrellas on the beach.